# .htaccess edit to hide folder in the server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to hide my folders inside my server to be shown in the URL, I have a website hosted by bluehost.  I tried several .htaccess change, but no luck.  Anyone care to let me know what i did wrong?  I am trying to have www.domain.com/application/models/login.php as www.domain.com/login.php instead.  I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^\/application\/models\/(.*)$ \/login\.php$ [NC,L]
```

and this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^application\/models\/login\.php$ "http\:\/\/domain\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

But none of which works :(

Answer (score 0):

Put this in `.htaccess`  at your document root  :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?login.php$   application/models/login.php  [L]
```

Comment: I tried it just now and my domain is under ~/public_html/domain and I place it inside domain folder.

Comment: nothing, it still show www.domain.com/application/models/login.php

Comment: you want to enter `login.php`  and see the content of `/application/models/login.php`  or you want to enter `/application/models/login.php` in address bar and get redirected to `login.php`?

Comment: I want to have www.domain.com/application/models/login.php to show as www.domain.com/login or www.domain.com/login.php ... it still direct to the folder but I just want to hide the folders path inside the server

Comment: Clear browser's cache and try again!

Answer (score 0):

Put this .htaccess in your "models" folder:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

it will redirect www.domain.com/application/models/login.php to www.domain.com/login.php